# Not inserting a node in doubly linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes, doubly-linked-list

In my `add()` method I have to insert a node but the code happens not to add that node into the list. The add() method works with the iterator and adds the node with specified data to the list before the element that would be returned by a call to `next()`.
For example:

```
 SimpleList<String> list = new SimpleList<String>();
    list.add("A");
    list.add("B");
    list.add("C");
    list.add("D");
    list.add("E");
    System.out.println(l); // Output is [A,B,C,D,E]

    ListIterator<String> iter = list.listIterator();
    iter.add("1th");
    System.out.println(l);
```

The output after `iter.add("1th")` should be `[A, 1th, B, C, D, E]` but still gives me `[A, B, C, D, E]`. I tried to use a debugger but still nothing was clear to me. Could smb please help?

```
public class AListIterator implements ListIterator<T>{
        protected Node<T> current;                 // Current node, return data on call to next()
        protected Node<T> lastVisited = null;      // Used for calls to remove
        protected boolean lastMoveWasPrev = false; // Necessary for implementing previous()
        // Move the iterator forward and return the passed-over element
        public T next( ){
            if(!hasNext( ))
                throw new RuntimeException("Already at end of list"); 
            T nextItem = current.data;
            lastVisited = current;
            current = current.next;
            lastMoveWasPrev = false;
            return nextItem;
        }
public void add(T x){
            this.next();
            Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(x);
            newNode.prev = lastVisited;
            newNode.next = current;
        }
```

Comment: Not an answer, just a comment: As I guess, `add` method shouldn't throw an exception if a list is empty. It is **OK** and expectable to add items to the empty list.

Comment: You're creating a new node and setting its next and prev pointers, but you forgot to change the next and prev pointers of the nodes **surrounding** that node. Note that the new node, as per the javadoc, should be inserted **before** the element that would be returned by next().

Comment: @JBNizet So, `lastVisited.next = newNode; current.prev = newNode;` should work. However, this code will insert a new item **before** the current one while it is expected that it will be inserted after the current. Also, it will move iterator one move ahead - it is unobvious and may confuse developer \ user.

Comment: @JBNizet, Im still having troubles. I've changed the code and linked the surroundings: `lastVisited.next = newNode;
   newNode.prev = lastVisited;
   newNode.next = current;
   current.prev = newNode;` but still cannot get the desired result. Could you please take a look at the code in this comment one more time?